# theme functions (hooks)

Tags: hooks

This question was already asked in WordPress, but there was no answer for it. Just wanted to try in this forum if anyone knows about it because i have also same question.

> want to edit my theme having jquery slidebar, how do i go to that
>   script?, its showing up "$theme->hook('content_before');" in content
>   div tag.can anyone help please?

My Theme index.php contains below

```
<div id="main">

    <?php $theme->hook('main_before'); ?>

    <div id="content">

        <?php $theme->hook('content_before'); ?>

        <?php 
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                /**
                 * The default post formatting from the post.php template file will be used.
                 * If you want to customize the post formatting for your homepage:
                 * 
                 *   - Create a new file: post-homepage.php
                 *   - Copy/Paste the content of post.php to post-homepage.php
                 *   - Edit and customize the post-homepage.php file for your needs.
                 * 
                 * Learn more about the get_template_part() function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part
                 */

                get_template_part('post', 'homepage');

            endwhile;

            else :
                get_template_part('post', 'noresults');
            endif; 

            get_template_part('navigation');
        ?>

        <?php $theme->hook('content_after'); ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->

    <?php get_sidebars(); ?>

    <?php $theme->hook('main_after'); ?>

</div><!-- #main -->
```

Comment: couldn't understand your exact issue, a lil more detail will be helpfull. You are working on the theme itself or using a child theme? What are the complications in editing and what excatly you want to edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can take a look on this topic [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/comments-on-category), related to your question